# Playing HD videos on a low spec computer using USB-to-HDMI adapter

Tags: high-definition, video-playback

I have a computer branded FitPC3 that I am using as a file server, here are the specs:

- **CPU:**  AMD G-T40N (Dual-core) 1.00 Ghz (CPU-Z shows 1.33 Ghz)
- **GPU:**  AMD Radeon HD 6290 (384-MB DDR3 memory) + HDMI port
- **MEM:**  4-GB Memory (DDR3)

*(full CPU-Z/GPU-Z reports available)*

It has Windows 8 installed and it can play some 720p videos, depending how they're compressed, even when it can play them fairly OK it still chops during fast motion scenes..

I'm using Media Player Classic.

I tried to strip Windows to the max, stopped all unnecessary services, removed features, followed many performance enhancing guides..

I'm looking for advice on how to increase video playback performance, I'm thinking of getting a USB-to-HDMI adapter that supports 1080p resolution, example:

[eBay: USB 3.0 To HDMI Converter Adapter 1080P Graphic Video Display Card For Win 7/8](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/USB-3-0-To-HDMI-Converter-Adapter-1080P-Graphic-Video-Display-Card-For-Win-7-8-/131393236849?pt=US_Video_Cables_Adapters&hash=item1e97a5af71)

I wonder if it's going to bypass the weak video card in the PC and use the USB converter adapter instead. Is that possible?

Comment: I think your current video card is the bottle neck. 384mb seems kind of low. I would recommend at least 512mb or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different video player that support GPUs better. I would say your CPU is the bottleneck however as opposed to @rrirower. Try using VLC or CoreAVC.
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html
http://www.corecodec.com/products/coreavc
Also if you want to strip your Windows "to the max," play the video in safe mode.

Comment: Safe mode may not load everything needed.  If not, a clean boot might: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-clean-boot-state-in-windows

Comment: Didn't know about "clean boot", very nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the older Media Player Classic, or the newer Media Player Classic - Home Cinema, http://mpc-hc.org/, which plays 1080p video even on my vastly underpowered Acer D250 with 2 GB RAM and Intel Atom CPU. It may take some twiddling with settings to get the best display. Before investing in hardware, try the free software.

[Linux is pretty efficient, and you might try booting temporarily into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS or other distro from a USB drive, to see if you can play video without artifacts. There's no need to actually install the OS, just test to see if it's faster than Windows 8.]

Comment: Definatly adjust the render method, and restart the program with a different render method. MPC has multiple render methods, and different ones will take way more cpu or gpu use. if your already looking at hardware without adjusting the software, then you missed the "easy on the hardware" render methods.

Comment: Hey there. I am using "Media Player Classic - Home Cinema".. So just play with the output rendering? Thx for the advice, I will try and report back. PS. what O/S are you running on your Acer D250  ?